# Contextual closure type Response<AnyObject> -> void expects 1 agrument but 3 were in closure body

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

This code was fully working my previous project on iOS 8 and swift 2.0.

Here is my code:

```
let url=NSURL(string: _resourceURL)!

Alamofire.request(.GET ,url).responseJSON { (request : NSURLRequest?,response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, result: Result<AnyObject> ) -> void in
   print(result.value.debugDescription)
}
```

Now I try with iOS 9 , Swift 3.0, alamofire 4.0.0
but  throws the following error:

> Generic type 'Result' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)
>   Use of undeclared type 'void'
>   Contextual closure type 'Response -> Void' expects 1 argument, but 3 were used in closure body

Comment: `Result<AnyObject, NSError>`

Comment: @ozgur That will fix the generic type error however, there should only be one parameter, and that should be of type `Response<AnyObject, NSError>`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a particular object you need the JSON to be cast to and you're happy accessing the properties by key, you can just do this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { response in
    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The helpful elves at Alamofire wrote a terse but indispensable [migration guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md), including 'before/after'-style code snippets. Based on those, there are a few things you need to do with your code to work with AF 4.0:

1. Pass in your url as a `String` (which AF extends to conform to its own `URLConvertible` protocol), not as NSURL.
2. Switch the order of the URL and the method. ...
3. ...Swift 3 switches to lowercased enums ([SE-006](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md)), so the method is lowercase in AF 4+. ...
4. ...And while we're at it, `.get` is the default method, so we can just drop it altogether.
5. `URLResponse` and `URLRequest` no longer have the NS prefix.
6. Switch to the new `DataResponse` type, which contains our friends `result`, `request`, and `response`.

So working code might look like:

```
    // resourceURL
let url = "http://www.example.com/endpoint"

Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { dataResponse in
  guard 
    let request = dataResponse.request,
    let response = dataResponse.response
    else { fatalError("Don't ship me, debug me, master!") }

    print(dataResponse.result.value.debugDescription)
```

This compiled in XCode 8GM, but I haven't run it (no real endpoint), so grain of salt and all.